# matlab: How to get textured using triangulation points in 3d reconstruction

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, matlab-cvst, 3d-reconstruction

I am working on 3d Reconstruction from two views. Till now I have got Fundamental matrix, Essential matrix and Triangulation Points. After this stage, how do I go forward to obtain textured image from the input image? and save those results in VRML model?

Answer (score 0):

Are your cameras calibrated?  If so, then you can rectify the images, and get a dense reconstruction. You can then plot the points using the colors from the RGB image.  See this [example](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/stereo-calibration-and-scene-reconstruction.html?refresh=true).